# How to change security class of a file using NSFileManager?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Ho do the following lines to change the security class of a file translate into MT?

Change the class of a file: `-[NSFileManager setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:]`

Attribute: `NSFileProtectionKey (NSFileProtectionComplete, NSFileProtectionNone)`

How do I change the class of a file in MT?

And even more: If I manage to change the class, how can I verify that it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
NSError error;
var dict = new NSMutableDictionary ();
dict.SetObject ("NSFileProtectionComplete", "NSFileProtectionKey");
mgr.SetAttributes (path, dict, out error);
```

Comment: Okay. So there are no consts (yet). I see. Thx.